# Is there an analogue of the Hille Yosida theorem for abstract Cauchy problems of the type $ \frac{du(x,t)}{dt}=A(t)u(t,x)+Cu(t,x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I have the following abstract Cauchy problem on a Banach space $X$: 
$$ \frac{du(x,t)}{dt}=A(t)u(t,x)+Cu(t,x)$$
where $A(t)$ is a closed, densely defined, linear, bounded operator for every $t \in [0,T]$.

Moreover, all the operators of the family $\{A(t): t \in [0,T]\}$ have the same domain $D(A) \subset X $, hence all the operators go from $D(A)$ to $X$.
Also $C$ is a linear bounded operator from $D(C)$ to $X$.

I would like to know if the operator $A(t)+C$ generates a strongly continuous semigroup. 
I know that this holds if $A$ does not depend by the time, but I do not find the analogue result in the case of $A$ depending by time.

Someone knows where this kind of problems are treated in literature ? 
Thank you

Comment: What are the properties of $\{A(t)\}$ and $D(C)$? Well, the answer is "yes" if $\{A(t)\}$ is stable and $D(C)=X$. See my post for more details and some references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $A$ depends on $t$, we have to talk about "family" of infinitesimal generators. In this context, your question can be formulated as follows:

**Does a family of generators retain the properties of a family of generators if subjected to perturbations?** (This is a version of [Kato](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&pg=PA497&dq=%22retain+the+properties+of+a+generator%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT_e3p69LYAhUIjpAKHckOAccQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22retain%20the%20properties%20of%20a%20generator%22&f=false), p. 497)

Of course, the answer depends on the properties of the family and the perturbations. We have, for example, the following result in [Pazy's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=DQvpBwAAQBAJ&pg=PP3&dq=Semigroups+of+Linear+Operators+and+Applications+to+Partial+Differential+Equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8oKSdvc_TAhUChJAKHfxODnQQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=Semigroups%20of%20Linear%20Operators%20and%20Applications%20to%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations&f=false) (p. 132):

> If $\{A(t)\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ is a stable family of infinitesimal generators of $C_0$-semigroups and $\{B(t)\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ is a family of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $X$ such that $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\|B(t)\|<\infty$, then $\{A(t)+B(t)\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ is a stable family of infinitesimal generators.

You can find more results in the paper [*Stability of CD-Systems Under Perturbations in the Favard class*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00009-013-0376-8) (there are other references in the third paragraph).